# jQuery - using current object in a function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, this

I would like to make this code work, but the .css function is returning `undefined`

```
$(".split-section-headings .ssh-cell")
    .html("This container has padding-top = " + $(this).css("paddingTop") );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code surrounding that statement. Is this in an event handler?

Comment: There is no code surrounding that. It is the only statement in a `<script>` tag at the end of the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `$(this)` without something similar to an `.each()` or in an event handler:

```js
$(".split-section-headings .ssh-cell").each(function() {
  $(this).html("This container has padding-top = " + $(this).css("padding"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="split-section-headings">
  <div class="ssh-cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Before opening this question, I had achieved the expected result with the following: `$(".split-section-headings .ssh-cell").html(function() { return "This container has padding-top = " + $(this).css("paddingTop") });` but I thought it was too dirty. May I ask you what do you think? :) Thanks